# I want to create a debugger extension for a language supported by gdb, can I extend another extension from an extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Basically, there is already the cpptools project which has a debugger for C/C++, I'm wanting to know if I can use this as a dependency in a new extension and add support for another language in the new extension overriding whatever needs to be overridden in the new extension for the new language. Or was cpptools debugger not developed with that in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Extensions could extend the capabilities of other extensions via the extension *exports* facility, but in this case, since you want to write a debugger for a language that is different from C/C++, you should write an extension that brings that language to VS Code (see the how to [contribute a language](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide)) and then implement a debugger for that language. VS Code provides the facility to launch the debugger and let the end-user step forward, set breakpoints, etc... You implement what those actions mean for your language.

See the [VS Code Extension Guide: Debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension). It refers to a working example: [Mock Debugger](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mock-debug.git).

You can theoretically modify this sample to your language, however, the Debugger protocol and the API itself is the hardest part of VS Code's (otherwise very clean and usable) API, in my opinion.

Comment: Opinion: The debugger extension point in VS Code is the darkest corner I wish was re-designed, or at least some simple API was layered over it for simple debuggers that do not need to integrate an already existing out-of-process runtime.